# Append unicode data to string in python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to append some binary data to a string file in python, when I get the following error :
`'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 408: ordinal not in range(128)`

My code looks like below:

```
binary = 'contains some binary data read from file'
#binary = binary.decode("utf-8")
str = 'packet header data'

packet = str + binary       #error here
```

I get the above error when appending the binary data to string. I have tried using encoding, and decoding too.

Edit:
I also get the same error when decoding the binary object.

Comment: is this python 2.x ?

Comment: yes it is python 2.x

Comment: `binary.decode("utf-8")` takes a utf-8 byte string and decodes it into a Unicode string. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: I just want to get rid of the error. I have tried without the binary.decode('utf-8') line. It then gives me the same error when appending.

Comment: If you just want to get rid of the error, then use `binary.decode("utf-8", "ignore")` to ignore the errors. ( [Docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) ). But using ignore or replace flag will cause data lost. IMO, that might not be what you want

Comment: @MayurMore, I presume your binary data is not text. Therefore, you don't need to decode it.

Comment: Maybe you should post a [MCVE] so we can reproduce your error. BTW, you shouldn't use `str` as a variable name, as that shadows the built-in `str` type. Doing that can cause mysterious errors, but I don't _think_ that's the cause of your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Either decode both, or start with a `unicode` literal.

```
str = u'packet header data'
packet = str + binary
```

Comment: I can decode the str object, but I get this error when decoding the binary object - <'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 408: invalid start byte>

Comment: @MayurMore  that error means binary object can not be decoded to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Python 2.x, you should not be receiving that exception when concatenating two strings.

The following works fine for me:

```
binary = '\x9d'
str = 'packet header data'
packet = str + binary
```

Your error is more likely to be coming from a `print` statement or a write to a file that has been opened in text mode.